# Confidence interval of the weighted mean

Tags: gis

In a sampling survey, I get $N$ cases about whether to support a policy
and get $x_i(i=1,2,..,N)$, $x_i$ is binary, support $x_i=1$, and $x_i=0$ otherwise, give a weight $w_i(i=1,2,..,N)$to every case, finally I get the odds of support $$O =  \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^N w_i \cdot x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i}$$
I confused with how to get the 95% confidence interval of $O$,and $\delta-method$ ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)) can be used to solve the question?
Thanks